# Swift: Value of type has no member 'peformSelector'

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm trying to implement protocol/delegate using performSelector but I'm getting this error:

```
Value of type 'DoingSomething' has no member 'peformSelector'
```

Here is my implementation:

```
import UIKit
protocol DoingSomethingDelegate {
    // delegate function
}

class DoingSomething {
    func goDoSomething()  
        self.performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(self.processSomething()), with: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
    }
    func processSomething() {

        print("I'm done")
    }
}
```

But if I move the functions to the viewController I have no errors. Any of you knows why of the error or how can I fix this error?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: It's an `NSObject` method and your class doesn't inherit from `NSObject`

Comment: Consider `DispatchQueue.main.sync`. `performSelector...` is outdated (in Swift).

Comment: @dan, adding NSObject to the class made the trick: class DoingSomething:NSObject

Comment: It just occurred to me that calling `performSelector(onMainThread:with: waitUntilDone:)` from the main thread and with a wait parameter of true is pointless. It is special-cased to be a direct call to the specified selector. In GCD, a sync call **from** the main thread **to** the main thread is a one-way trip to a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

Per @dan comment I made the changes:

```
class DoingSomething:NSObject {

    func goDoSomething()  {

        self.performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(self.processSomething), with: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
    }

    func processSomething() {

        print("I'm done")
    }
}
```

Now is working!

Comment: This is not a good solution. Why add the needless baggage of extending `NSObject` just so you can call `performSelector` when the much better solution is to do as @vadian stated and use `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

Comment: @rmaddy, why DispatchQueue.main.sync is better option then performSelector ?

Comment: Because you are using Swift. Why extend `NSObject`? And using `DispatchQueue` gives you so many more options. `performSelector` is very limited and it too easy to get the `#selector` syntax wrong.

Comment: @user2924482, see my answer. I go into some detail about the advantages of using DispatchQueue's function instead of performSelector.

Answer (score 1):

As @vandian suggests in his comment, you should think about using GCD instead. The equivalent code would be:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.processSomething()
}
```

There are a couple of advantages to using async(). You can provide the code in-line without having to write a separate function, which makes it easier to read and maintain; The closure you execute has access to the enclosing scope, so you can use variables from your function inside that code, e.g.:

```
func localScopeFunc {
  var x: Int = 6
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    //This block of code has access to the local variables from localScopeFunc
    print("x = \(x)")
  }
}
```

With performSelector() and it's variants you can only invoke functions with zero, one, or 2 arguments, and those arguments must be `NSObjects`.

Forcing an object to be a subclass of `NSObject` also has some minor down-sides to it. That forces the compiler to use dynamic dispatching, which is slightly slower than the static dispatching that Swift uses.

Comment: performSelector has the option to wait until is done. Does DispatchQueue.main.async it will wait until process the block of code ?

Comment: @user2924482 If you want to wait, and you know 100% that you are not already on the main queue, then use `DispatchQueue.main.sync` instead of `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

Comment: @rmaddy, that make sense. Thank you